# Rename multiple .docx files in a folder using a script task

Tags: python, windows, powershell

I have 453 files in a folder (all of type .docx
the problem is these files need to be renamed in a proper format

```
Vendor1_FinanceReport.docx
Vendor5_FinanceReport.docx
Vendor17_FinanceReport.docx
Vendor91_FinanceReport.docx
```

I want to rename this into something like

```
Vendor1_FinanceReport_Oct_2020.docx
Vendor5_FinanceReport_Oct_2020.docx
Vendor17_FinanceReport_Oct_2020.docx
Vendor91_FinanceReport_Oct_2020.docx
```

Comment: Why all `Oct_2020` ? Shouldn't the code append the month and year taken from the actual file's modification date?

Comment: Actually only October files are in that folder sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this on powershell:

```
Get-ChildItem | rename-item -NewName { $_.BaseName + "_Aug_2020" + $_.Extension}
```

or this in CMD

```
for %%a in (*) do ren "%%~a" "%%~na_Oct_2020%%~xa"
```

Comment: This will try and rename every item in the current path.. (both folders and files will be affected)

Comment: The powershell command worked , thank you so much @DKM

Comment: @ShreyaDutta If the code is correct, please mark it as "Correct" this will help other users

Answer (score 1):

For safety, I have put the `Get-ChildItem` line between brackets, so the code does not acidentally iterate files that already have been renamed.

By adding the `-File` switch, you can be sure only **files** are renamed, not folders.
Also, by using the `-Filter` the code wil only affect .docx files

```
$rootFolder = 'path\to\the\folder\where\the\files\are'
$append     = '_Oct_2020'  # hardcoded as per your comment

(Get-ChildItem -Path $rootFolder -Filter '*.docx' -File) | 
 Rename-Item -NewName { '{0}{1}{2}' -f $_.BaseName, $append, $_.Extension }
```